# How do i go about fetching this musical file from mysql music table to js

Tags: javascript

AM creating a musical playlist on a php website and i have this bellow code.
How do i go about  fetching this musical file from mysql music table to this js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myPlaylist = [

    {
        mp3:'mix/Masterkraft.mp3',
        oga: 'mix/Masterkraft.mp3',
        title:'Indomie(Remix)',
        artist:'Masterkraft',
        rating:4,
        duration:'0:30',
        cover:'mix/1.png'

    },
    {
        mp3:'mix/Masterkraft.mp3',
        oga: 'mix/Masterkraft.mp3',
        title:'Indomie(Remix)',
        artist:'Masterkraft',
        rating:4,
        duration:'0:30',
        cover:'mix/1.png'

    }
];

   </script>
```

Comment: I will appropriate a sample code for handling this

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by ajax call [example](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php) and get a json of playlist